# Spatialite: 'no such function: GeomFromText' error

Tags: spatialite, php, sqlite

I've this PHP code on my Ubuntu 15.10 virtual machine

```
<?php    
  $lon = 4.221542;
  $lat = 32.21115;

  $db_data_sessions = new SQLite3('./DataBase/MyDB.sqlite');

  # Loading SpatiaLite as an extension ...
  $db_data_sessions->loadExtension('mod_spatialite.so');

  $q="SELECT comune FROM comuni32632 WHERE 
      WITHIN(Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." 
      ".$lat.")',4326),32632),comuni32632.Geometry)";

      echo "Query = " .$q;
      echo "\n\n";

      try {
        $stmt = $db_data_sessions->prepare($q);
        $results = $stmt->execute();

        if ($results->fetchColumn() > 0)
         {
           echo "OK";
           echo "\n\n";

           $theName = '';
           while($row=$results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
             {
              $theName = $row['comune'];
             }
           //return $theName;
           echo "Result = " .$theName;
           echo "\n\n"; 
         }
         else {
            //return "NO DATA";
            echo "Result = NO DATA";
            echo "\n\n";
         }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e) {
        print "Something went wrong or Connection to database failed! ".$e->getMessage();
        //return "ERROR";
        echo "Result = ERROR";
        echo "\n\n";   
   }
   $db_data_sessions = null;    
?>
```

and when I try to execute I can see only the first echo output, so my current query text and not more. In the browser console I can see "Error 500"

When I try to execute from command line

```
php test.php
```

the result is

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::loadExtension(): SQLite Extension are disabled in /var/www/html/test.php on line 10
Query = SELECT comune FROM comuni32632 WHERE WITHIN(Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(4.221542 32.21115)',4326),32632),comuni32632.Geometry)

PHP Warning:  SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such function: GeomFromText in /var/www/html/test.php on line 19
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /var/www/html/test.php on line 20
```

Note that if I try to execute the query in Sqlite3 loading the Spatialite extension all works fine

Note that if I try to execute the PHP test code available here http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/php.html all works fine so I think that PHP and Spatialite are working fine together

What is going wrong in my code?

Comment: Feels like sqlite does not allow to load extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved changing my code in this way ....

```
<?php

  $lon = 11.611378;
  $lat = 45.730675;

  $db_data_sessions = new SQLite3('./DataBase/OpenProntoSoccorso.sqlite');

  # Loading SpatiaLite as an extension ...
  $db_data_sessions->loadExtension('mod_spatialite.so');

  $q="SELECT comune FROM comuni32632 WHERE WITHIN(Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")',4326),32632),comuni32632.Geometry)";

  echo "Query = " .$q;
  echo "\n\n";

  try {
     $stmt = $db_data_sessions->prepare($q);
     $results = $stmt->execute();

     $count = 0;
     while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
       $data .= $row['comune'];
       $count = $count + 1;
     }
     echo "Result = OK - Comune = ".$data." Count = ".$count;
     echo "\n\n";
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
        print "Something went wrong or Connection to database failed! ".$e->getMessage();
        //return "ERROR";
        echo "Result = ERROR";
        echo "\n\n";

  }
  $db_data_sessions = null;

?>
```